# How to add a key-value pair to a plist file in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm working on an iPhone app and I need to add a new key-value pair to an existing plist file using objective-c. This is what I've tried so far:

```
NSString *myFile=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Favourites" ofType:@"plist"];

dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:myFile];
[dict setObject:textContent forKey:keyName];
[dict writeToFile:myFile atomically:YES];
```

However, when I do this it doesn't write it to the file. I've only seen resources based on either changing the value of a key or adding to another key. Is there another way to accomplish this?

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot make any changes in the bundle. So what you have to do is copy the `.plist` file into your documents directory and do the manipulation there.

Something along these lines:

```
//check for plist
//Get documents directory's location
NSArray*docDir=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString*filePath=[docDir objectAtIndex:0];
NSString*plistPath=[filePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Favourites.plist"];

//Check plist's existance using FileManager
NSError*err=nil;
NSFileManager*fManager=[NSFileManager defaultManager];

if(![fManager fileExistsAtPath:plistPath])
{
    //file doesn't exist, copy file from bundle to documents directory

    NSString*bundlePath=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Favourites" ofType:@"plist"];
    [fManager copyItemAtPath:bundlePath toPath:plistPath error:&err];
}

//Get the dictionary from the plist's path
NSMutableDictionary*plistDict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
 //Manipulate the dictionary
 [plistDict setObject:textContent forKey:keyName];
 //Again save in doc directory.
 [plistDict writeToFile:myFile atomically:YES];
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I tried your code snippet and it didn't really work as expected. What I'm basically trying to do is be able to click a UIBarButtonItem and then add an entirely new key plus a value associated with the key. I think the setObject and forKey are only based on if the key already exists

Comment: @user1186173, so you want to add a new key and a new value for an existing value and key ? For that you can use `removeObjectForKey` method. `[plistDict removeObjectForKey:@"keyYouDontWant"]` then set new object with that key or a different key. `[plistDict setObject@"ex" forKey@"newKey"]`

Comment: @user1186173, additionally if you wan to check if key already exists. You can try `NSMutableDictionary`'s `allKeys` property and check if your key exists. I can edit if you require that too.

Comment: I think it's working, I just put in a UIAlert that displayed the value of the new key and it was the right one. Thank you very much!

Comment: @user1186173, Sweet!, glad to help.