# Plist is not creating in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist, nsmutabledictionary

When i got my server response and trying to save that in plist, but plist file is not creating.

I have logged file path and dictionary contents but all these have data still plist not creating

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [self sideMenu:@"ML"]; 

    return YES;
}
```

this will call following method

```
-(void)sideMenu:(NSString *)title{

    NSString *myRequestString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"data=%@&deviceid=e8ef8c98262185ec",title];

    NSData *myRequestData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[myRequestString UTF8String ] length: [ myRequestString length ] ];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [ [ NSMutableURLRequest alloc ] initWithURL: [ NSURL URLWithString:SIDE_MENU]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody: myRequestData];
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *err;
    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse:&response error:&err];
    NSString* responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSArray *myArray = [responseString componentsSeparatedByString:@"<!DOC"];
    //NSLog(@"%@",myArray);
    if (myArray != nil || [myArray count] > 0) {
        NSData *data = [[[myArray objectAtIndex:0]stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
        [self sideMenuFile:title :json];
    }



}




-(NSString *)sideMenuFile:(NSString *)titleName :(NSDictionary *)dict{
    NSString *filePath;
    MyManager *sharedManager =[MyManager sharedManager];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    if([titleName isEqualToString:@"ML"])
    {   sharedManager.sideMenu = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];
        sharedManager.sideMenu = dict;
        filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ML.plist"];
    }else if ([titleName isEqualToString:@"HM"]){
        filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"HM.plist"];

    }else if ([titleName isEqualToString:@"PDC"]){
        filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"PDC.plist"];

    }else if ([titleName isEqualToString:@"SM"]){
        filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"SM.plist"];

    }else if ([titleName isEqualToString:@"GL"]){
        filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"GL.plist"];

    }else if ([titleName isEqualToString:@"CU"]){
        filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"CU.plist"];

    }else if ([titleName isEqualToString:@"BR"]){
        filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"GL.plist"];

  }

    NSLog(@"%@",filePath); //printing path
    [dict writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

    NSString *basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;

    NSString *plistName = @"GL";
    NSString *finalPath = [basePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                           [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@.plist", plistName]];

    NSDictionary *dictww=[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:finalPath];




    NSLog(@"dict%@",dictww); //printing nill


    return filePath;
}
```

JSON file structure

```
{
    sigallery =     {
        rows =         (
                        {
                active = True;
                gallerytext = "<null>";
                galleryurl = "assets/img/content-images/1.jpg";
                moddt = "2016-07-19T12:28:18.873";
                onclickurl = "testd.in";
                settingsid = 1;
                showfromdt = "1901-01-01T00:00:00.0";
                showsequence = 1;
                showuptodt = "2099-12-31T00:00:00.0";
                videoimagebanneraudioswitch = I;
            },
                        {
                active = True;
                gallerytext = "<null>";
                galleryurl = "assets/img/content-images/2.jpg";
                moddt = "2016-07-19T12:28:18.873";
                onclickurl = "testd.in";
                settingsid = 1;
                showfromdt = "1901-01-01T00:00:00.0";
                showsequence = 2;
                showuptodt = "2099-12-31T00:00:00.0";
                videoimagebanneraudioswitch = I;
            }
            )
            }
            }
```

Comment: Refer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12170871/how-to-add-a-key-value-pair-to-a-plist-file-in-objective-c and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23867337/how-can-i-save-retrieve-delete-update-my-data-in-plist-file-in-ios

Comment: `[finalPath isEqualToString:filePath]`? Declaring/Naming your method `sideMenuFile:noTextHere:` is clearly NOT recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Your code makes a number of non-optimal assumptions.

1)

Whenever you write out a file, you should always check for any error condition if it's available. NSDictionary's `writeTo...` methods do return Booleans whether the file has been written out or not, so you could do:

```
NSLog(@"%@",filePath); //printing path
BOOL success = [dict writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
if (success == false)
{
     NSLog(@"did not successfully write dictionary to path %@", filePath);
} else {
    //  ... do everything else in here
}
```

2)

You write out files wih the format `titleName` + `GL | PDC | SM.plist` but when you try to read things back in, there is no `titleName` as part of the `finalPath`, so nothing lines up here.

3)

Also, why do you assume `basePath` is valid (it looks like it could be nil)?